# Remove a character from file names in every folder in a particular folder

Tags: powershell, batch-rename

Using a script, I managed to inadvertently rename everything in a users home folder on the server-- such that each file in every folder (and folders within the folders) were renamed to have a "$" at the end.  All I was trying to do was rename each user's home folder to foldername$, to be hidden when searching for shared folders.

To make a long story short, I figured out how to get rid of the "$" from every file in one folder, but it doesn't apply it to all the child folders:

```
get-childitem * | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("$","") }
```

Does anyone know how to modify this to remove the $ symbols from the end of every file in every folder under a folder?

Thanks!

Comment: *I was trying to do was rename each user's home folder to foldername$, to be hidden*...Google **Access-based Enumeration** and use that instead!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*$" -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Replace("$","") }
```

- `-Filter` is much faster than a where/foreach.
- `-Recurse` iterates through subfolders
- Rename-Item accepts piped input.

Comment: Your [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) could benefit from more detail. Please edit it to explain what this command does/how it works.